# java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1058220 bytes

Tags: java, android

I am getting this when i capture image through recycle view item but the code works fine for the first item and on the second item when i capture photo it gives following error.

> E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size =
>   1058220) E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.xtremesolutions.vehicleinspection, PID: 8139
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1058220
>   bytes
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3982)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
>                      Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1058220 bytes
>                         at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
>                         at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:617)
>                         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3632)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3974)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)

**Code:**
This code is in viewholder

```
    @OnClick(R.id.btn_attach_picture) void onAttachPictureClicked(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                photoFile = getPhotoFileUri();
                Uri fileProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.itemView.getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider", photoFile);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileProvider);
            }
            //intent.putExtra("questionId",item.getQuestionId());
            QuestionAdapter.CURRENT = item.getQuestionId();
            if (intent.resolveActivity(this.itemView.getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                //((Activity)this.itemView.getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
            final int[] count = {0};

            final Handler h =new Handler();
            Runnable runnable =new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    count[0]++;
                    if (count[0] < 50){
                        if (!item.getEvidence().equals("")){
                            attachPicture.setText("Picture Attached");
                            attachPicture.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#d63031"));
                        }else{
                            h.postDelayed(this,500);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            h.postDelayed(runnable,2000);

        }
```

and this code is in fragment

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bitmap photo;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                }
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, byteArrayOutputStream);
                byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                String evidence = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                int count = 0;
                for (Question question:
                     this.questions) {
                    if (question.getQuestionId() == CURRENT){
                        question.setEvidence(evidence);
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MessageHelper.showMessage("Error", e.getMessage(), fragment.getContext());

        }
    }
```